# How to pair array with radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic understanding of Java and C++ but I am still very new to Javascript & html. I am trying to create 5 buttons which will initiate a small addition quiz. The first number will be a random number from 0-12 but the second number will be static. The second digit will depend on the selection of the user. I have been searching for a while on how to obtain an integer by using a radio button. I would like to find this in order to implemented on the array. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```js
function startAdd(){
  const Add_One = 1;
  var answer;
  var random = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++){

    random.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13));
    console.log(random[i]);

}
//  console.log(Add_One);
//  var x = prompt('Enter something lil boi');
//    var num1 = parseInt(x);
//  console.log(x);


  for(var a = 0;a < 21; a++){

    document.write(random[a] + " + " + Add_One + " =" + "<br>" );

//    if(random[a]+Add_One = answer )

  }

}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>RicoMath</h1>
<h1 class = "add">Addition</h1>
<h2>Difficulty</h2>
          <div class="options">
            <div>
              <input id="num1" type="radio" name="dif" value="1">
              <label for="num1">1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="num2" type="radio" name="dif" value="2">
              <label for="num2">2</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="num3" type="radio" name="dif" value="3" checked>
              <label for="num3">3</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="num4" type="radio" name="dif" value="4">
              <label for="num4">4</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="num5" type="radio" name="dif" value="5">
              <label for="num5">5</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button onclick = "startAdd()">Begin!!!!</button>

</body>
```

Comment: You tagged your question with jquery, yet you seem to be trying to avoid it at all costs. You did not even include the library in your snippet. Any reason for that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very new to jquery. The only reason I tagged it was because I am open to the idea of using it to solve this problem. Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: Out of all your questions you have `NO accepted answers`. Please vote on answers and mark helpful ones as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned already in my comment to your question, you have not been using jquery at all. Here is a rudimentary example of how you can get jquery to do some of the work for you:

```js
for (var opts=[],i=1;i<6;i++)  // first: build the radio button menu
  opts.push('<input id="num'+i
            +'" type="radio" name="dif" value="'+i
            +'"><label for="num'+i+'">'+i+'</label>');
$('div.options').html(opts.join('<br>\n'));

$('button').click(function(){  // define the click action
  var dif=$("input[type=radio][name=dif]:checked").val();
  // or: dif=$(".options :checked").val();
  console.log('difficulty from checkbox: '+dif);
  const Add_One = 1;
  var answer, random = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++){
    random.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+' + '+Add_One+' =');
  }
  $('.questions').html(random.join('<br>\n'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>RicoMath</h1>
<h1 class="add">Addition</h1>
<h2>Difficulty</h2>
<div class="options"></div>
<button>Begin!!!!</button>
<div class="questions"></div>
</body>
```

I used `dif=$("input[type=radio][name=dif]:checked").val();` to get the current difficulty value. An alternative, shorter selector for the same job could also be `dif=$(".options :checked").val();`, as you only have one group of radio buttons in the `<div class="options">`.

Whatever you do - you should avoid using `document.write()` at all costs, as it messes up your document structure.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand right what you want to do with the number, but here's how you can get it!

**jQuery**

```
var second_digit = $('input[name="dif"]:checked').val();
```

**javascript**

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("dif");
var second_digit = null;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        second_digit = radios[i].value;
        //skip other radios as only one can be selected
        break;
    }
}
```

If the read value is string, just do

```
second_digit = second_digit * 1;
```

or

```
second_digit = Number(second_digit);
```

This will cast to number.